# How many downvotes in a row does it take for count as "serial downvoting"?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Shortly after criticizing an answer for lacking sources or any detail, I noticed that three of my old posts were downvoted within the span of a few minutes. I suspect retaliatory downvoting considering that all of them occurred within a few minutes of each other and these posts had been sitting dormant for **weeks**.

[image]

I reported the incident and waited 24 hours for the Stack Exchange [serial downvoting script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/513519) to reverse it, but nothing happened. I was under the impression that SE took this seriously, so my question is, what does it take for such obviously retaliatory action to be considered "serial downvoting"? 4 downvotes, 5...?

Comment: Just to give a little more context to Criggie's answer...The mods on this site have *some* visibility into voting patterns, but we can't see specific votes. I can't get into specifics, but I looked into this specific case and could find no evidence of serial downvoting. I actually do see some evidence that it's *not* serial downvoting. I understand that it looks strange, but it really does appear to be coincidence.

Comment: @jimchristie I can actually see the same user commenting in one of the same threads as a downvoted post *at the same time* as the serial downvoting occurred. This thread had remained dormant for 28 days until my post was downvoted. The other threads were inactive for 23 days and 27 days respectively. I find it extremely hard to believe that all of this downvoting and comment activity happened within a few minutes of the dispute on **weeks** old dormant threads and that it's all just a coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

The thresh hold for the serial downvoting detection script is **5 downvotes** in the 24 hour window from the same user.

3 downvotes is -6, and is less than one upvote (+10)  Try giving a good answer to one of the other questions to recover the balance and then some.

Comment: He's back at it again (third time): Now on english SE: https://i.imgur.com/H7ILPqw.png https://i.imgur.com/GGfkSEc.png (last seen 12 hours ago - same time) -- How many times does this have to happen before someone does something?

Comment: @Benjamin I have escalated this to Community Mods, now that it has transitioned to other SE sites.  More info as it comes to hand.

Comment: Any word yet? BTW, the downvoting detection script didn't trigger, even with 7 in a row: https://i.imgur.com/U7ZpwQE.png?1 (Could you could try talking to him? Thank you.)